# mysql query to retrieve rows based on different keys and timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

we have a "transactions" table that's recording a variety of events happening on our website. One in particular needs a nightly "cleanup" process run on it. Here's my columns (simplified):

```
id, txName, brandName, visitorID, txDate
```

Here's what I want to retrieve (in prose):

> "READ" `txName's` from `vistiorID's` that haven't recorded a "READ" `txName` in the last 6 weeks (based on `txDate`) for a particular `brandName`.  It's entirely possible (and likely) that `visitorID` will have "READ" `txName's` for more than one `brandName` during the 6 week window. We only have 5 `brandName's` so I'm totally content building a process for a single `brandName` and repeating it 5 times.

My brain can only stretch as far as doing 2 MySQL SELECT queries (records prior to 6 weeks, records within 6 weeks), then looping through the two sets a few times to get an array of final records that have to be processed. But I'm sure there's a WAAAAY more efficient way that I just don't understand.

I hope this makes sense...thank you anybody that can help. I think the part that's really messing me up is trying to select people who *haven't* logged a transaction, versus those who *have*

Comment: Do you just want to select any records where the txDate was more than 6 weeks ago?

Comment: good question. I realize I'd only need a single instance of each visitorID (per brandName). and I only need a specific type of txName (the entry is called "READ", sorry if that confused anybody who thought the word "READ" had something to do with reading the table).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(visitorID) 
    FROM transactions 
   WHERE txName = "READ" 
     AND txDate <= '$6weeksago'   
GROUP BY brandName
```

Where `$6weeksago` is a variable created in PHP to represent the time of the 6 week cut off in the required format `(not sure if it was a date or Unix timestamp)`.

I haven't tested this as I don't have the table, but I think it is what you are after!

Comment: that would be the first of my two queries if I can't come up with a more efficient way to do this. the second would be "SELECT DISTINCT (visitorID) FROM transactions WHERE txName = "READ" AND txDate >= '$6weeksago' GROUP BY brandName" (in other words, the inverse of the timetable). And then I'd compare the two sets of records to exclude those records that have the visitorID present in both sets. But can this be accomplished in one query?

Comment: I can't think of away :(  Like you, I'd probably pull both queries into arrays and do the compare.   However, you can use php's array_key_exists function to gain some efficiency during the loops, and avoiding looping through the second array for every key in the first array.  You just loop through Array1, and checking if the same key exists in Array2 as you go.  So it should avoid you needing to loop through multiple times...